# Connection is not private in localhost

Tags: asp.net

I am getting an error while debugging a asp.net web application . It says 
"Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from localhost (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards)".This server could not prove that it is localhost;

It's security certificate is from some other machine .What steps should I follow to fix this? Is there a problem if I continue anyway ? Since it is just on localhost.

Comment: What hostname is the certificate issued to? Sounds like you either have a certificate for your "normal" hostname (and not explicitly localhost).

Comment: It says Its security certificate is from the same machine I am trying to run on. ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Comment: That sounds like what I described, you created a certificate for the hostname "simon-pc" but accessing it through "localhost". Does it work if you use your network name (in my example "simon-pc""?

Answer (score 12):

I know it's a bit old post. However, I have been searching for more than an hour to find a solution to this trivial yet irritating problem and I just found a solution.

1. You need to export the certificate from chrome. Open the url. Click the lock icon > Certificate Information > Details tab > Hit Copy to file.
2. You need to import the certificate into Windows. Open Run (Windows button + R) > type `certmgr.msc` > Expand to Trusted Root Certifications Authorities | Certificates > Action (from the menu bar) > All Tasks > import (now import the file you exported from the previous step).

This worked for me.

Comment: Did not help... :(

Comment: This is the one that actually finally worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use port of 8000 insted 80

Fortunately, modern browsers consider http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to be a “[potentially trustworthy](https://www.w3.org/TR/secure-contexts/#is-origin-trustworthy)” URL because it refers to a loopback address. Traffic sent to 127.0.0.1 is guaranteed not to leave your machine, and so is considered automatically secure against network interception.
[read more from letsencript](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/)